# SharePoint online REST APIs used in a Java Application

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

We are creating a proprietary application in Java that needs to perform operations on SharePoint online.

Our application is completely void of the .Net framework since it will be hosted on a Ubuntu server.

Since REST APIs are application-agnostic; we want to use the SharePoint Online REST APIs to perform these operations.

How do we go about doing that? What authentication methods are available to us?